# Need help in implementing WCF authentication and authorization in internet context

Tags: wcf, silverlight, security

I need to create a wcf service which would be consume by silverlight apps downloaded through internet. Basically the users are not part of any windows domain but there credentials and roles are maintained in database.

1. The wcf service should be internet enabled, but methods cannot be accessed anonymously.
2. Authorization should also be supported\
3. User and roles tables are not as per ASP.NET membership schema
4. Developers should not be constrained to have IIS installed and certificate configured
5. Authorized users should be able to access only his related information. He should be able to delete or update his related companies but not others.

To achieve 1 & 2, i had followed below link.

[WCF security by Robbin Cremers](http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/08/wcf-message-security-with-username-authentication-and-authorization-provided-by-a-membership-provider/)

To cover point 3, i have provided custom implementation of MembershipProvider and RoleProvider classes and overridden methods ValidateUser and IsUserInRole respectively to fetch from my own schema user and roles table.

So far, so good authentication and authorization works fine.

Now the problem, the developers can't have IIS installed and certificates configured, so need to disable this in development mode. Hence have implemented custom CodeAccessSecurityAttribute class which would check development mode or production and use custom IPermission or PrincipalPermission.

[Question 1]My question is I don't anywhere people recommend this approach, so litte afraid whether this is the right approach or any better approach is there to handle this situation.

[Question 2] Lastly related to point 5, do i need to send some kind of token over? What is the best approach for this?

[Question 3] Performance impact in Robbin Cremers method, since for every service call, two extra database calls will be made in "ValidateUser" and "IsUserInRole" to authenticate and authorize. Is there a better way?

Sorry for the big question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your scenario description, once you've created and hooked up your custom Membership / Role providers, you don't really need Message Security. Instead, the standard approach described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560702(v=vs.95).aspx will work just fine (or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560704(v=vs.95).aspx if you want users to log in via your Silverlight app instead of via a regular web page). The browser then handles the sending of any required tokens automatically (via cookies), and I'm guessing ASP.NET is smart about caching authentication/authorization results so the overhead should not be incurred on every call.